# HTML range input is unresponsive on attempts to move

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I try and move the thumb across the track nothing happens. It stopped working after I added an `img` inside the `slider-cntnr` `div`. http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/xVEXvB

#### HTML

```
<div id="slider-cntnr">
  <img id="slider-background" src="http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/file/n5009735/OCT_pre_segmented.png"></img>
  <input type="range" id="frame-slider" oninput="updateFollowerValue(this.value)" />
  <div id="slider-follow-cntnr">
    <div id="slider-follow">
      <div id="slider-val-cntnr">
        <span id="slider-val"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slider-cntnr {
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#frame-slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#slider-follow-cntnr {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 98%;
}

#slider-follow {
  background-color: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

#slider-val-cntnr {
  background-color: white;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
}

#slider-val {
  margin-left: 9px;
}

#slider-background {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

#### JS

```
var follower = document.getElementById('slider-follow');
var follower_val = document.getElementById('slider-val');
var slider = document.getElementById('frame-slider');

var updateFollowerValue = function(val) {
  follower_val.innerHTML = val;
  follower.style.left = (val*1) + '%';
};

updateFollowerValue(slider.value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following CSS will make it work.

```
#slider-cntnr input{
  position:relative;
}
```

I also added the following, because it may be annoying to accidently drag the image instead.

```
img {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

See [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPrqOr)

Comment: I believe you couldn't drag because #slider-follow-cntnr was on top of it, because it is positioned relatively, and the input is not. When you position an element relatively, it's Y-position is on top of statically positioned elements. Since the input is now too positioned relatively, with the same z-index of 0, they follow the order of occurrence to determine who is on top of who.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `margin-top` to the slider input. Currently the mouse grabs the image, not the slider bit.